# For example VS for an example

Tags: american-english, british-english, clauses, indefinite-article

I always read this (for example), but **example** is a countable noun. So, I think it should be '**for an example**'.

**Please check both sentences and let me know, which one is correct:**

> Knowing the weather will help you prepare your clothes, as well as
>   plan your commute. **For example**.

**VS**

> Knowing the weather will help you prepare your clothes, as well as
>   plan your commute. **For an example**.

**Please note**:

> My focus is just on **for an example** or **for example**. I do not care about
>   the entire sentence.

Comment: [For example](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for+example) is an idiom. Also, it is not a complete sentence on its own.

Comment: So, which one I should use when I am going to talk about an example?

Comment: Its typical pattern is: *"For example, ..."* Let's say that you're explaining the importance of information. You can give your example like this: *"Information is very important in our daily life. For example, knowing the weather will help ..."*

Comment: Thank. And if I use 'for an example' instead of 'for example', will it be right?

Comment: That is what I'm not very sure. Usually, if an idiom exists, other similar alternative will subside. It could look odd if you used it. I would recommend not to use it. But saying that "for an example" is wrong is another matter. And I believe that you can get better answers from others.

Comment: 'For an example' would not be correct here.  There are other ways to give examples:  let me give you an example, let's look at an example, to take only one example...

Comment: @DamkerngT. Don't believe this is a duplicate, because _"for an example"_ **could** be correct in some cases, and you can't tell from the example sentences. That said, it is clearly related to the other question... (granted, I may not be clear as to what marking a question as "duplicate" means for the question)

Comment: @AlicjaZ I wasn't aware of the duplication until I saw three votes to close, and once I saw the other question, imho, it's a duplicate. In any case, I believe that your mentioning of "For an example of X", though the OP didn't ask about it (and you seem to agree that using "for an example" the way the OP suggested is not a good idea), is useful.

Comment: @AlicjaZ You can vote to reopen if you don't think it's a duplicate.  If you want to have further discussion, you can start a meta thread (which will draw more attention and make it more likely that the question gets reopened).

Comment: @snailplane Gotcha. I actually literally just now got my close/reopen rights, but I'll wait a while to figure things out before I start making a mess of things :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's likely that *"for example"* is the correct phrase in this case, and is a widely used idiom in English, but it depends on what you want to say.

If you want to provide an example right then and there, you need to say *"For example"* or - if you really want to use the article - you could say *"As an example"* or *"An example might be"*, or any such construct. A sample sentence might be:

> *For example, one way to clean silver coins is to wash them with water.*

Note that in such a case, you can't use the plural: **"For examples, ways to clean coins include water and baking soda"* would be wrong.

However, there are also situations in which using *"for an example"* would be perfectly acceptable and, in fact, the only correct thing to write:

> *For an example of how to clean silver coins, refer to this book.*

Note that the phrase *"for an example"* here is used differently than *"for example"* in the previous sentence. Instead of specifically providing an example, the speaker is only telling people where they can find that example. And, in such a case, you should definitely use the *"an"* article.

Note that here, you can use the plural: **"For examples of how to clean coins, refer to this book"* would imply that the book contains many examples, not just a single one.

Looking back at your example sentences, here is how both of your sentences could be continued:

> *Knowing the weather will help you prepare your clothes, as well as plan your commute. For an example of how to dress appropriately, you may wish to look at photographs of locals taken in the season you will be travelling.*
>
> *Knowing the weather will help you prepare your clothes, as well as plan your commute. For example, if you are travelling to Warsaw in November, you should definitely pack a raincoat, as Poland is very rainy then.*

Answer (score 5):

**For example** is very widely used in English. **For an example** *may* be technically correct, however it is almost never used in conversation or writing. Sometimes something like '**An example of this is:**' or '**An example would be:**' could be used.

Comment: _For example_ is a very widely used idiom. _For an example_ by itself is grammatically correct, but very rare usage. You can say, _For an example **of this situation,** recall that..._. You can also say, _As an example, **recall that**..._.